# Match substring of two vectors and create a new vector combining them

Tags: r, vector

Consider two vectors.

```
a <- c(123, 234, 432, 223)
b <- c(234, 238, 342, 325, 326)
```

Now, I want to match last two digits of `a` to first two digits of `b` and create a new vector pasting first digit of `a`, the matched part and  last digit of `b`. My expected output is :

```
[1] 1234 1238 2342 4325 4326 2234 2238
```

For simplicity purpose consider all the elements would always be of length 3.

I have tried :

```
sub_a <- substr(a, 2, 3)   #get last two digits of a
sub_b <- substr(b, 1, 2)   #get first two digits of b
common <- intersect(sub_a, sub_b)
```

`common` gives me the common elements in both `a` and `b` which are :

```
[1] "23" "34" "32"
```

and then I use `match` and `paste0` together and I get incomplete output.

```
paste0(a[match(common, sub_a)], substr(b[match(common, sub_b)], 3, 3))
#[1] "1234" "2342" "4325"
```

as `match` matches only with the first occurrences.

How can I achieve my expected output?

Comment: Hmm... A not very efficient way can be `d1 <- expand.grid(a, b); d2 <- expand.grid(sub_a, sub_b); i1 <- d2$Var1 == d2$Var2; do.call(paste0, d1[i1,])` and then remove duplicates from each string

Comment: I don't think `match` will suit you there as it stops after first match. Probably more like `sub_a %in% sub`

Comment: @Sotos that works except that `common` part is repeated twice in the final output. Can we make it more efficient? I am already using so many extra variables (`sub_a`, `sub_b`, `common`), adding two more would be expensive?

Comment: look at this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47435067/3521006

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ yes, I am aware of that.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
a <- setNames(a, substr(a, 2, 3))
b <- setNames(b, substr(b, 1, 2))

df <- merge(stack(a), stack(b), by = 'ind')
paste0(substr(df$values.x, 1, 1), df$values.y)
```

which gives:

> ```
> [1] "1234" "1238" "2234" "2238" "4325" "4326" "2342"
> ```

---

A second alternative:

```
a <- setNames(a, substr(a, 2, 3))
b <- setNames(b, substr(b, 1, 2))

l <- lapply(names(a), function(x) b[x == names(b)])
paste0(substr(rep(a, lengths(l)), 1, 1), unlist(l))
```

which gives the same result and is considerably faster (see [the benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47435067/2204410)).

Comment: Very nice @Jaap. Never occurred to me to that it's possible to use `stack` on a named vector; I'm curious: Is this documented somewhere? I couldn't find anything in `?stack`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers If it isn't in `?stack` then I wouldn't know of another source which documents this :-\

Comment: @MauritsEvers I have to come back at my previous comment: it **is** in the documentation of `?stack`, but only implicit in the last line of the details section: *These functions are generic: the supplied methods handle data frames and __objects coercible to lists__ by `as.list`* (emphasis mine). And a named vector is coercible to a list.

Answer (score 13):

Probably a little complex but works:

```
unlist( sapply( a, function(x) {
  regex <- paste0( substr(x, 2, 3), '(\\d)')
  z <- sub(regex, paste0(x, "\\1"), b)
  z[!b %in% z] 
} ))
```

which give: `[1] "1234" "1238" "2342" "4325" "4326" "2234" "2238"`

The main idea is to create a regex for each entry in a, apply this regex to b and replace the values with the current a value and append only the last digit captured (the `(\\d)` part of the regex, then filter the resulting vector to get back only the modified values.

Out of curiosity, I did a small benchmark (adding sub_a and sub_b creation into Sotos and Heikki answers so everyone start on the same initial vectors a of 400 observations and b of 500 observations):

```
Unit: milliseconds
            expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
      Jaap(a, b) 341.0224 342.6853 345.2182 344.3482 347.3161 350.2840     3
     Tensi(a, b) 415.9175 416.2672 421.9148 416.6168 424.9134 433.2100     3
    Heikki(a, b) 126.9859 139.6727 149.3252 152.3594 160.4948 168.6302     3
     Sotos(a, b) 151.1264 164.9869 172.0310 178.8474 182.4833 186.1191     3
 MattWBase(a, b) 286.9651 290.8923 293.3795 294.8195 296.5867 298.3538     3
```

Answer (score 11):

Another way could be to use `expand.grid`, so picking up at your `sub_a` and `sub_b`,

```
d1 <- expand.grid(a, b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
d2 <- expand.grid(sub_a, sub_b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
i1 <- d2$Var1 == d2$Var2
d1 <- d1[i1,] 
d1$Var1 <- substr(d1$Var1, 1, 1)

do.call(paste0, d1)
#[1] "1234" "2234" "1238" "2238" "2342" "4325" "4326"
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's another option in base R:

```
foo <- function(a, b) {
  split_a <- split(a,  substr(a, 2, 3))
  split_b <- split(substr(b, 3, 3), substr(b, 1, 2))
  idx <- intersect(names(split_a), names(split_b))
  stopifnot(length(idx) > 0)
  unlist(Map(function(x,y) outer(x, y, paste0), split_a[idx], split_b[idx]), 
                      use.names = FALSE)
}

foo(a, b)
# [1] "1234" "2234" "1238" "2238" "4325" "4326" "2342"
```

---

Update:

I used the function definitions from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47435067/3521006 to make another benchmark with all answers and larger data.  The input data and results I got are:

```
set.seed(123)
a <- sample(100:999, 1e4, TRUE)
b <- sample(100:999, 1e3, TRUE)

library(microbenchmark)
library(dplyr)
res <- microbenchmark(docendo(a, b), 
               Jaap1(a, b), 
               Jaap2(a, b), 
               Sotos(a, b), 
               Tensi(a, b), 
               Heikki(a, b), 
               Matt_base(a, b),
               Matt_dplyr(a, b), 
               zx8754(a, b),
               times = 10, unit = "relative")

Unit: relative
             expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
    docendo(a, b)   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000    10
      Jaap1(a, b)  14.002977  13.724432  13.347755  13.433175  12.788948  13.301811    10
      Jaap2(a, b)   4.364993   4.936248   5.201879   5.125639   5.060425   7.520069    10
      Sotos(a, b)  22.215750  23.850280  25.743047  25.177676  28.274083  28.288089    10
      Tensi(a, b) 231.230360 234.830000 246.587532 242.345573 260.784725 273.184452    10
     Heikki(a, b) 135.615708 136.900943 144.775845 146.314048 150.546406 156.873954    10
  Matt_base(a, b)  13.274675  12.995334  13.402940  12.723798  12.432802  18.881093    10
 Matt_dplyr(a, b)   1.299223   1.314568   1.420479   1.345850   1.380378   1.807671    10
     zx8754(a, b)   9.607226  10.175381  10.486580  10.136439  10.096818  13.410858    10
```

Interestingly, when I reproduce the comparison of Frank's answer and mine from the benchmark, I get opposite results:

```
Frank <- function(a, b) {
  aDT <- as.data.table(tstrsplit(a, ""))
  bDT <- setnames(as.data.table(tstrsplit(b, "")), c("V2", "V3", "V4"))
  merge(aDT, bDT, allow.cartesian = TRUE)[, paste0(V1, V2, V3, V4)]
}

set.seed(1)  # same input size as in the cw benchmark answer
a <- sample(100:999, 8e3, TRUE)
b <- sample(100:999, 1e4, TRUE)

microbenchmark(Frank(a, b), docendo(a, b), unit = "relative", times = 10)

Unit: relative
          expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
   Frank(a, b) 1.37435 1.390417 1.500996 1.470548 1.644079 1.616446    10
 docendo(a, b) 1.00000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    10
all.equal(sort(docendo(a, b)), sort(Frank(a, b)))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Nice one and the fastest! See benchmark in the separate cw-answer.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an approach where the first list `a` is gone through in a `for` loop. In each loop iteration the last two digits of an element in list `a` are matched against the first two digits of list `b`. The results are combined to vector `result`.

```
a <- c(123, 234, 432, 223)
b <- c(234, 238, 342, 325, 326)

sub_a <- substr(a, 2, 3)   # get last two digits of a
sub_b <- substr(b, 1, 2)   # get first two digits of b

result <- c()
for (ai in a) {
    sub_ai <- substr(ai, 2, 3)
    if (sub_ai %in% sub_b) {
        b_match <- (sub_b == sub_ai)
        result <- c(result, paste0(ai, substr(b[b_match], 3, 4)))
    }
}
result
```

This yields

```
[1] "1234" "1238" "2342" "4325" "4326" "2234" "2238"
```

In case `a` or `b` does not contain only unique value, you may unique results with command

```
unique(result)
```

Answer (score 8):

Using *dplyr::inner_join* on the middle pieces:

```
library(dplyr)

a <- c(123, 234, 432, 223)
b <- c(234, 238, 342, 325, 326)

a1 <- data.frame(a)
b1 <- data.frame(b)

a1 <- a1 %>% mutate(first_a = substr(a, 1, 1), last_a = substr(a, 2, 3))
b1 <- b1 %>% mutate(first_b = substr(b, 1, 2), last_b = substr(b, 3, 3))

c1 <- inner_join(a1, b1, by = c("last_a" = "first_b"))

results <- paste0(c1$a, c1$last_b)
```

---

Using *base::merge*:

```
a1 <- data.frame(a)
b1 <- data.frame(b)

a1$first_a = substr(a1$a, 1, 1)
a1$last_a = substr(a1$a, 2, 3)
b1$first_b = substr(b1$b, 1, 2)
b1$last_b = substr(b1$b, 3, 3)

c1 <- merge(a1, b1, by.x = "last_a", by.y = "first_b")

results <- paste0(c1$a, c1$last_b)
```

Answer (score 8):

A benchmark (adding sub_a and sub_b creation into Sotos and Heikki answers so everyone start on the same initial vectors `a` of 800 observations and `b` of 1000 observations).

Running the benchmark with:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

a <- sample(100:999, 8e3, TRUE)
b <- sample(100:999, 1e4, TRUE)

microbenchmark(Jaap1(a,b), Jaap2(a,b), Tensi(a,b), Heikki(a,b), Sotos(a,b),
               Matt_base(a,b), Matt_dplyr(a,b), Docendo(a,b),
               zx8754(a,b), zx8754for(a,b), Frank(a,b),
               times = 50, unit = 'relative')
```

gives:

> ```
> Unit: relative
>              expr        min         lq        mean     median         uq        max neval      cld
>       Jaap1(a, b)  19.668483  19.316194  17.2373827  18.921573  18.829932  7.8792713    50    d    
>       Jaap2(a, b)   4.253151   4.365420   4.0557281   4.309247   4.398149  2.2149125    50  b      
>       Tensi(a, b) 241.682216 238.197815 212.2844582 233.473689 233.367619 93.3562331    50        h
>      Heikki(a, b) 114.895836 113.754054 101.2781709 111.637570 110.541708 44.9437229    50       g 
>       Sotos(a, b)  27.598767  28.725937  25.7469518  28.534011  28.638413 11.6995642    50     e   
>   Matt_base(a, b)  19.159883  18.834180  16.8853660  18.513498  18.416194  7.8329323    50    d    
>  Matt_dplyr(a, b)   1.108230   1.106051   1.0203776   1.102078   1.098476  1.0131898    50 a       
>     Docendo(a, b)   1.000000   1.000000   1.0000000   1.000000   1.000000  1.0000000    50 a       
>      zx8754(a, b)  11.601730  12.986763  11.7859245  13.054720  13.234842  5.6944437    50   c     
>   zx8754for(a, b)  90.448168  92.906445  82.4905438  91.092609  90.160010 36.1277145    50      f  
>       Frank(a, b)   1.070775   1.070202   0.9621499   1.063978   1.055540  0.4459918    50 a
> ```

---

The used functions:

```
Jaap1 <- function(a,b) {
  a <- setNames(a, substr(a,2,3))
  b <- setNames(b, substr(b,1,2))

  df <- merge(stack(a), stack(b), by = 'ind')
  paste0(substr(df$values.x,1,1), df$values.y)
}

Jaap2 <- function(a,b) {
  a <- setNames(a, substr(a,2,3))
  b <- setNames(b, substr(b,1,2))

  l <- lapply(names(a), function(x) b[x == names(b)])
  paste0(substr(rep(a, lengths(l)),1,1), unlist(l))
}

Tensi <- function(a,b) {
  unlist(sapply(a,function(x) {regex <- paste0(substr(x,2,3),'(\\d)'); z <- sub(regex,paste0(x,"\\1"),b); z[!b %in% z] } ))
}

Heikki <- function(a,b) {
  sub_a <- substr(a, 2, 3)
  sub_b <- substr(b, 1, 2)
  result <- c()
  for (ai in a) {
    sub_ai <- substr(ai,2,3)
    if (sub_ai %in% sub_a) {
      b_match <- (sub_b == sub_ai)
      result <- c(result,paste0(ai,substr(b[b_match],3,4)))
    }
  }
  result
}

Sotos <- function(a,b) {
  sub_a <- substr(a, 2, 3)
  sub_b <- substr(b, 1, 2)
  d1 <- expand.grid(a, b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  d2 <- expand.grid(sub_a, sub_b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  i1 <- d2$Var1 == d2$Var2
  d1 <- d1[i1,] 
  d1$Var1 <- substr(d1$Var1, 1, 1)

  do.call(paste0, d1)
}

Matt_base <- function(a,b) {
  a1 <- data.frame(a)
  b1 <- data.frame(b)

  a1$first_a = substr(a1$a, 1, 1)
  a1$last_a = substr(a1$a, 2, 3)
  b1$first_b = substr(b1$b, 1, 2)
  b1$last_b = substr(b1$b, 3, 3)

  c1 <- merge(a1, b1, by.x = "last_a", by.y = "first_b")

  results <- paste0(c1$a, c1$last_b)
}

Matt_dplyr <- function(a,b) {
  a1 <- data.frame(a)
  b1 <- data.frame(b)

  a1 <- a1 %>% mutate(first_a = substr(a, 1, 1), last_a = substr(a, 2, 3))
  b1 <- b1 %>% mutate(first_b = substr(b, 1, 2), last_b = substr(b, 3, 3))

  c1 <- inner_join(a1, b1, by = c("last_a" = "first_b"))

  results <- paste0(c1$a, c1$last_b)
}

Docendo <- function(a, b) {
  split_a <- split(a,  substr(a, 2, 3))
  split_b <- split(substr(b, 3, 3), substr(b, 1, 2))
  idx <- intersect(names(split_a), names(split_b))
  stopifnot(length(idx) > 0)
  unlist(Map(function(x,y) outer(x, y, paste0), split_a[idx], split_b[idx]), 
         use.names = FALSE)
}

zx8754 <- function(a, b) {
  unlist(sapply(a, function(i) i * 10 + (b %% 10)[i %% 100 == b %/% 10]))
}

zx8754for <- function(a, b) {
  res <- integer()
  for(i in a)  res <- c(res, i * 10 + (b %% 10)[i %% 100 == b %/% 10])
  res
}

Frank <- function(a, b) {
  aDT <- as.data.table(tstrsplit(a, ""))
  bDT <- setnames(as.data.table(tstrsplit(b, "")), c("V2", "V3", "V4"))
  merge(aDT, bDT, allow.cartesian = TRUE)[, paste0(V1, V2, V3, V4)]
}
```

Answer (score 8):

How about a bit of maths*:

```
unlist(sapply(a, function(i)
  i * 10 + (b %% 10)[i %% 100 == b %/% 10]))
```

---

*Assumption: all numbers are 3 digits, but this of course can be adjusted within sapply.

Check output, the output will be in different order than other answers, and output is numeric, not character.

```
identical(sort(as.numeric(docendo(a, b))), sort(zx8754(a, b)))
# [1] TRUE
identical(sort(as.numeric(jaap(a, b))), sort(zx8754(a, b)))
# [1] TRUE
```

---

**Edit:** forloop version seems 3x faster (with example small data, with bigger set it is actually 3x slower, see benchmarks wiki post).

```
zx8754 <- function(a, b) {
  unlist(sapply(a, function(i) i * 10 + (b %% 10)[i %% 100 == b %/% 10]))
}

zx8754_forloop <- function(a, b) {
  res <- integer()
  for(i in a)  res <- c(res, i * 10 + (b %% 10)[i %% 100 == b %/% 10])
  res
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  zx8754 = zx8754(a, b),
  zx8754_forloop = zx8754_forloop(a, b)
)

# Unit: microseconds
#           expr    min      lq     mean median     uq      max neval
# zx8754         16.535 17.3910 55.05348 17.676 18.246 3672.223   100
# zx8754_forloop  4.562  5.4165 46.74887  5.987  6.272 4080.469   100

#check output
identical(zx8754(a, b), zx8754_forloop(a, b))
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to put it into columns and join:

```
library(data.table)
Frank <- function(a, b) {
  aDT <- setDT(tstrsplit(a, ""))
  bDT <- setnames(setDT(tstrsplit(b, "")), c("V2", "V3", "V4"))
  merge(aDT, bDT, allow.cartesian = TRUE)[, paste0(V1, V2, V3, V4)]
}
```

or [@MattW's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47431677/) in data.table:

```
MattDT <- function(a,b){
  aDT2 <- data.table(V1 = substring(a,1,1), V23 = substring(a,2,3))
  bDT2 <- data.table(V23 = substring(b,1,2), V4 = substring(b,3,3))
  merge(aDT2, bDT2, allow.cartesian = TRUE)[, paste0(V1, V23, V4)]
}
```